# How do I compare the symbol a with the character a?

Tags: scheme

I have a list containing letters.
When I do (car '(a)) it gives me the symbol a.
How do I compare it to the character a?

Must I do (eq? (car list) (car '(a))?

Comment: @Robert Harvey Whoa! Kinda harsh? Maybe give the asker 5 minutes to rephrase? Looks like they accidentally submitted the incomplete question. @Andre Viau `'(a)` is a quoted list, and `car` takes the head of that list. In this case, `a` is a symbol. Symbols are an atomic datatype present in many Lisps and in Scheme. You can check for types by various type predicates, like `list?`, `symbol?`, `number?`.

Comment: A question that doesn't even finish sentence #3 is not a question. It's just noise. If the OP bothers to finish it, it can be re-opened.

Comment: Sorry, so yeah, its a symbol thanks!.... I'll go look into converting a symbol into a char.

Comment: @Andre Viau `char=?` won't work because it's not a character. If you want to compare symbols, use `eq?`. If you want the character from the symbol, you could do `(string-ref (symbol->string 'a) 0)` but post some more information about what you're trying to do, and maybe the SO mods will graciously let you ask a question.

Comment: Oops! didn't see hidden comments. Ah well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols and characters are different kinds of data.  Fortunately, Scheme is willing to let you convert nearly anything you want. In Racket, for instance:

```
#lang racket

;; the symbol a:
'a

;; the character a:
#\a

;; are they equal? no.
(equal? 'a #\a) ;; produces #f

;; converting a character to a symbol:
(define (char->symbol ch)
  (string->symbol (string ch)))

(char->symbol #\a) ;;=> produces 'a

;; converting a symbol to a character
(define (symbol->char sym)
  (match (string->list (symbol->string sym))
    [(list ch) ch]
    [other (error 'symbol->char 
                  "expected a one-character symbol, got: ~s" sym)])) 

(symbol->char 'a) ;; => produces #\a
```

With all that said, if you're working on a homework assignment, the instructor almost certainly has an easier path in mind for you.